# remove 0's from before number in string using jquery/regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following code:

```
var tagsUrlPrint = activeTags.join('+').replace(/_/g, ": ");
$('.test span').html(tagsUrlPrint);
```

which outputs the following in the dom:

color: brushed-bronze+color: gold+size: 06+size: 08+size: 15

but no matter how many different regex combinations I try, nothing is outputting any stripped 0's before the number (e.g. size:6, size: 8, etc)

i've tried:

```
var tagsUrlPrint = activeTags.join('+').replace(/_/g, ": " | /\0b+/g, "" );
 var tagsUrlPrint = activeTags.join('+').replace(/_/g, ": " | /\b0+/g, "" );
  var tagsUrlPrint = activeTags.join('+').replace(/_/g, ": " | /^0/g, " " );
  var tagsUrlPrint = activeTags.join('+').replace(/_/g, ": " | /^[0|\D]*/," ");
 var tagsUrlPrint = activeTags.join('+').replace(/_/g, ": ", /^0+/, " ");
```

all which have basically added an extra 0! I don't know why, but I can't wrap my head around the multiple regex i'm trying to achieve. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: replace `/\b0+(?=[1-9])/` with nothing or `/0+([1-9]\d*)/` with `$1` https://regex101.com/r/erAfWa/1

Comment: Spec seems unclear but `s.replace(/\b0+(?=\d)/g, "")` might help? Can you clarify what the input string is and what the output string should be precisely? What's the output for, say, `"00 01 0002 0"`? I'm not sure what `activeTags` is. Best to leave the DOM out of it if that part is working. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful. I will use that site from now on.